# Ubuntu 22.04 has problems detecting my Logitech webcam

Tags: 22.04, webcam, logitech

My Ubuntu 22.04 installed on a Tuxedo Infinibook 15 has problems detecting my **Logitech C925e** webcam.

After cold boot, it's rarely working and sometimes lighting the green light but no software using the camera. Software does not recognize the camera then.

When I re-plug the cam, its working.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 025: ID 046d:085b Logitech, Inc. Logitech Webcam C925e
```

During boot (before LUKS), there are a couple of messages:

```
Nov 21 07:59:03 en339 kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Nov 21 07:59:03 en339 kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Nov 21 07:59:03 en339 kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Nov 21 07:59:03 en339 kernel: usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
Nov 21 07:59:03 en339 kernel: usb 1-1: device not accepting address 4, error -62
Nov 21 07:59:03 en339 kernel: usb 1-1: device not accepting address 5, error -62
```

This happens on **cold boot only**, not on reboot. `Cheese` then does not detect the external webcam.

The camera is connected to the laptops own USB port but connecting to the dock leads to the same behavior. Tried multiple ports.

There are also failures on boot that state it's waiting for some USB device. I have no USB drives connected.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Would it be possible to update your question to include some of those boot failures? Notebooks do a lot more with USB than just storage devices 

Comment: Just tried a reboot and there was nothing. They appeared before I unlocked LUKS. Seems it happens only on "cold" hardware. Will add it as soon as I see them again. Filtering journalctl -b leads to thousands of lines containing "usb".

Comment: I updated the question :-)

Comment: Generally an `error -110` is referring to a lack of power provided on the serial bus. This can happen if there are too many devices connected to the same USB port. If this is happening for a built-in bus that you cannot plug anything into, it may be a sign of impending hardware failure or electrical problems 

Comment: Hm, I have connected Keyboard, Mouse and Yubikey to a Aimos USB switch. Indeed, the RGB keyboard sometimes misses keypresses. But it has no powersupply and I don't connect devices like USB sticks or webcams here. Tried once and they are not working.

Comment: This is the issue with the device itself. It has the same behaviour on Windows 10 and 11. Cold boot - no camera, disconnecting and connecting solves it.